# round shaped image using css

Tags: css, css-shapes

Here I created the image with round shape. But it covers all corners.
I want affect only in left corners.

CODEPEN: [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/AhEje)

```
.circular {

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
```

I appreciate if some one can improve this to display it similar to image in the CODEPEN. `circular` class is in bottom of css section

also needs help in positioning two labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make specific corners round by using `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius`, `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`.

Comment: Do you mean arranging things horizontally?

Comment: yes. without bootstrap css I got it done. I would like to see it using if someone can try

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
.circular {


   border:5px solid;
   border-top-left-radius:150px;
   background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorthand your css to a one-liner as well. Just remember, the border order in shorthand goes:

top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left

So if you want to control a specific border, do this:

```
.circular { 
    border-radius: 150px 0 0 150px; 
    background: url("image path") no-repeat; 
}
```